# Sulla's comment in Grass Crown

Tags: phrases

While reading 'Grass Crown' by Colleen McCullough, I came across what Sulla said as follows;
"I was given the hardest consulship a man has ever had. Just as I was given the hardest life a man has ever had. I'm not the kind to surrender, and I'm not the kind to care how I win. ***There are plenty of eggs in the cups and plenty of dolphins down.*** But the race won't be over until I'm dead."
What does that bold type sentence mean?

Comment: Obviously, you have never been to an ancient Roman chariot race :-).

Comment: I can't access the full text, but I see this at some earlier point: [*“With only one egg in the cup and only one dolphin down,” Sulla said, “you've got a very long way to go yet.”*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8xiDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT1033&lpg=PT1033&dq=%22egg+in+the+cup%22+%22dolphin+down%22&source=bl&ots=aQYWLOSSF0&sig=w4ZxCrcYGgVjZfRsoM06VIHLu-o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRpLyMy7XTAhWPLVAKHSQnCrUQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22egg%20in%20the%20cup%22%20%22dolphin%20down%22&f=false) Presumably if you're *reading* it you should know what Sulla is referring to there.

Comment: ...perhaps the allusion is to an egg-and-spoon race where the other person (Aurelia) is competing against a field composed solely of dolphins. But I still think whereas it should be obvious to anyone actually reading the book, it's not part of the ELU remit for *us* to go looking for the relevant information. It's context-specific, not to do with use of English as such.

Comment: I read "The Grass Crown" 12 years back and cannot now recall the reference to eggs and dolphins, but the **tone**, the context and the explicit declaration "I don't care how I win" suggests that Lucius Cornelius Sulla is determined to succeed AT ANY COST without being concerned about the consequences. (If you want the specific meaning, you will have to track down the reference to eggs and dolphins in the earlier part of the novel.)

Comment: Yes, I should have picked up the meaning from earlier conversation between Sulla and Aurelia. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because insufficient context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ancient Rome, at chariot races in the Circus Maximus, large wooden eggs and bronze dolphins were used to keep track of the number of laps that had been run (vaguely reminiscent of scoreboards at modern sports games). [See this web page](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/circusmaximus/circusmaximus.html).

So:

> There are plenty of eggs in the cups and plenty of dolphins down.

simply means that the race has been underway for quite a while.

This is not an English idiom, and probably not even a Latin one.